# Why does my Flutter app throw dex error while installing application on my device?

Tags: android, flutter

How to resolve dex error which says it can't load more than 65K while installing.

Comment: you have to enable multi-dex

Answer (score 0):

In your `android/app/build.gradle` set `multiDexEnabled` to `true`, as:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xyz"
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```